# Will devices auto connect to hidden WLANs?

Tags: wireless-networking

I am planning on making my WLAN hidden (not for security reasons, its pretty pointless in that regard). The network has never been hidden before, so none of the devices have it entered manually, just saved from when they normally connected. If I now hide the network, will these devices still connect to it automatically or not?

Thanks.

Note: There are reasons specific to my circumstances preventing me from just trying it out to see what happens

Comment: This depends on the OS. Android does connect to hidden WiFi APs, but on Windows you have to configure that manually.

Comment: And android does this even if it was never told that the network is private?

Comment: Sorry, I just checked this and it appears to not switch. It only connects after manually adding it.

Answer (score 0):

It is typically a setting in the connecting OS.

In Windows, you can look at the connection properties, and set 'Connect automatically'. If this flag is set, Windows tries to connect to this network, without even checking if it is there:

[image]

If you already connected before and didn't set the flag, just select 'Disconnect', and then open the dialog again, check the box, and chose 'Connect'

Other OS probably have similar settings, more or less well hidden.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So then windows will connect to it even if it hasn't been manually entered?

Comment: yes. It doesn't matter how it was connected the first time; it will always connect when the flag is set. Note that one time you need to type the password of course (if you have one). It doesn't just bypass the password checking.

Comment: Even if the network is hidden? I find that hard to believe, its a security risk then, since to do this it would constantly have to broadcast the ssid.

Comment: Yes, correct. That's exactly why it is _not_ a good idea to hide the SSID - all devices that know it will continuously cry for it, and anyone can listen to that.

Comment: But even if I didn't hide the ssid, from what you're saying it will still broadcast the ssid, which is the part I find hard to believe. If nothing has told the computer to expect the ssid to be hidden, why would it do that?

Comment: Because it wants to connect to the network? You told it to try that, right? How would it connect to the network without asking the network to answer?

Comment: Because when the network is not hidden, the computer will find out when it can connect to it. If you havent told the computer that it is private, it should only try to connect to it if it can see the network.